# Apple M1 minikube no service URL

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm working on Apple Silicon M1 Max and I'm trying to access service through web browser, but `minikube service nginx` opens blank web browser tab with some address (for example `http://192.168.49.2:31542/`) which fails to load. In log below you can notice output from `minikube service list` has no URL in `URL` column. Command `minikube service nginx --url` does not return any URL as well.

```
$ minikube start --driver=docker
  minikube v1.25.2 on Darwin 12.3 (arm64)
    ▪ MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD=minikube
✨  Using the docker driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.23.3 preload ...
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v17-v1...: 419.07 MiB / 419.07 MiB  100.00% 22.15 Mi
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=7903MB) ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.23.3 on Docker 20.10.12 ...
    ▪ kubelet.housekeeping-interval=5m
    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...
    ▪ Configuring RBAC rules ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default

 $ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx && kubectl create service nodeport nginx --tcp=80:80
deployment.apps/nginx created
service/nginx created

 $ kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        12m
nginx        NodePort    10.104.191.210   <none>        80:31542/TCP   12m

 $ minikube service list
|-------------|------------|--------------|-----|
|  NAMESPACE  |    NAME    | TARGET PORT  | URL |
|-------------|------------|--------------|-----|
| default     | kubernetes | No node port |
| default     | nginx      | 80-80/80     |     |
| kube-system | kube-dns   | No node port |
|-------------|------------|--------------|-----|

$ minikube service nginx --url

  Starting tunnel for service nginx.
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

Any ideas why there is no service URL and I am not able to access service from web browser?

Comment: I replicated it on Minikube on Linux and its worked. Unfortunately I don't have a Macbook to check and it could be issue with Docker Desktop.  You can try `Enable Kubernetes` option in Docker Desktop in `Settings>Kubernetes`. Cluster will be created automatically and you will be able use `kubectl` commands in few minutes in terminal. After your Deployment will be created, you will be able to open web browser and check using URL `localhost:port_number`. Let me know if it will solve your issue!

Comment: try kubectl port-forward service/service-name, it will work also refer to following on GIT https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193

Answer (score 1):

The network is limited if using the Docker driver on Darwin, Windows, or WSL, and the Node IP is not reachable directly.

Run service tunnel

```
minikube service nginx
```

Check ssh tunnel in another terminal

```
$ ps -ef | grep docker@127.0.0.1
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -N docker@127.0.0.1 -p 55972 -i /Users/FOO/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa -L TUNNEL_PORT:CLUSTER_IP:TARGET_PORT
```

Open in your browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:TUNNEL_PORT
```

ref:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-service-with-tunnel