# Cannot Connect to $(minikube ip):$NODE_PORT on mac M1

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am learning kubernetes on minikube. I studied the kubernetes official documentation and followed their [interactive tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-interactive/) in a sandboxed environment. Everything worked fine in the sandbox but I tried the same thing on my system it failed.

#### My Setup :

- I am using macOS Big Sur version 11.6.2(20G314) on Apple M1.
- I have used docker instead of virtual machine environment for minikube.

#### Steps to reproduce :

First I created a deployment, then I created a `NodePort` type service to expose it to external traffic.

The pod is running fine and no issues are seen in the service description.

To test if the app is exposed outside of the cluster I used `curl` to send a request to the node :

```sh
curl $(minikube ip):$NODE_PORT
```

But I get no response from the server :

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.XX.X port 32048: Operation timed out.

I have copied everything that was done in the tutorial. Same deployment name, same image, same service-name, literally EVERYTHING.

I tried `LoadBalancer` type, but found out that minikube doesn't support it. To access the `LoadBalancer` deployment, I used the command `minikube tunnel` but this did not help.

What could be the possible reasons? Is it my system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also had this problem on my m1 mac. I was able to access the service by using this command :

```sh
kubectl port-forward svc/kubernetes-bootcamp 8080:8080
```

You can see [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/minikube-tips-tricks-739f4b00ac17) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71667587/apple-m1-minikube-no-service-url) for more info and ways to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what minikube [driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) you are using "docker", "qemu" , etc.

If you are using the Docker driver (which is the default for minikube macOS) then you are supposed to use `minikube tunnel` and `minikube service xxxx` to get access to a NodePort.

With qemu2+socket_vmnet you can connect to the `minikube ip` and port directly (no need for `minikube tunnel`/`minikube service xxx`:

```
brew install socket_vmnet
sudo brew services start socket_vmnet
minikube delete --all
minikube start --vm --addons=ingress,dashboard
  minikube v1.30.1 on Darwin 13.3.1 (arm64)
✨  Automatically selected the qemu2 driver
  Automatically selected the socket_vmnet network

kubectl create deployment hello-minikube1 --image=kicbase/echo-server:1.0
kubectl expose deployment hello-minikube1 --type=NodePort --port=8080
kubectl get service
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello-minikube1   NodePort    10.109.118.67   <none>        8080:30521/TCP   0s
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          2m10s

kubectl get service hello-minikube1 --output='jsonpath={.spec.ports[0].nodePort}'
30521

curl  -m 2 "http://$(minikube ip):30521" 
Request served by hello-minikube1-8587cd9b85-zrpz6
```